# YouTube API returns zero results

Tags: python-2.7, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using YouTube API to retrieve videos data. I have a list of videos IDs.
For some of the videos the results that returns are normal and for some of them the API returns zero results. Via my browser all the results are valid.
Here is my code:

```
def getVideoDuration(self,videoId):
        try:
            content = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics%2C+contentDetails&id=" + videoId +"&key=" + self.DEVELOPER_KEY).read()
            jsonContent= json.loads(content)
            duration = jsonContent['items'][0].values()[0]['duration']
            if len(duration) == 7:
                minutes = jsonContent['items'][0].values()[0]['duration'][2]
                seconds = jsonContent['items'][0].values()[0]['duration'][4:6]
            if len(duration) == 5:
                minutes = 0
                seconds = jsonContent['items'][0].values()[0]['duration'][2:4]
            print minutes,seconds
            totalTime = str(minutes) + "." + str(seconds)
            return float(totalTime)
        except:
            return 0.0
```

For the ID: `'fu5K2cOeD4M'` my code return zero results, but via my browser the results are normal (JSON response attached):

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"0KG1mRN7bm3nResDPKHQZpg5-do/wTtZkXqw81l7Hq6-GrLwJ3wRQ5w\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"0KG1mRN7bm3nResDPKHQZpg5-do/jrxp-dHXG3s3ujaIjyq15GWV7V8\"",
   "id": "fu5K2cOeD4M",
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT8M15S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "sd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": false
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "18358",
    "likeCount": "166",
    "dislikeCount": "1",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "33"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

I tried to delay between my requests using time.sleep(), but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i sent the request i added an extra character

Comment: you should use regular expressions to parse the `duration`, or you should be 100% sure about the duration of video (less than 10 minutes)